# Jsoup Modify Links

Tags: spring, jsoup

I am, very new to spring and jsoup... I am using jsoup to parse an html file and copy some text inside a div tag and displaying it on my page. Now i am trying to modify the links and add exit.do to log the users out of the server. I have tried many different approach and my links dont work :( has anyone dealt with this link update before? any help is appriciated.

here is my code.

Thanks a lot.

Lola

```
modelMap = referenceData( request, modelMap);   
modelMap.put("externalUrl", externalUrlMap.get( request.getServletPath() ));
modelMap.put("elementId", elementIdMap.get( request.getServletPath() ));

/** Pass the url map to a string */
String url = (String) externalUrlMap.get( request.getServletPath() );

/** Pass the div map to a string */
String eleId = (String) elementIdMap.get( request.getServletPath() );

/** Retrieve and parse the document using Jsoup*/
//URL externalUrl = new URL(url);
//Document document = Jsoup.parse(externalUrl, 10000);
File internalFile = new File(url);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(internalFile, "UTF-8");

/** Clean the document to prevent XSS only include tags and style below */
//document = new Cleaner(Whitelist.basic().addTags("div", "em", "h1", "h2").addAttributes("div","class", "style")).clean(document); 

/** Select privactText tags from the id */
Element divContent = document.select(eleId).first(); 

/** Returned the text inside the div tag */     
String parsedExternalContent =  divContent.html();

/** Get all links inside div tag */
Elements links = divContent.select("a[href]");

String exitUrl = "/exit?logout=true&amp;uri="; 

/** Loop through the links and if the links are relative path add the exit.do to the link */
for (Element link : links) {            
    if (!link.attr("href").toLowerCase().startsWith("http://"))    {

        String urltext = link.attr("href");
        String exitText = "/exit?logout=true&amp;uri=";
        ...

    }
}               

modelMap.addAttribute("parsedExternalContent", parsedExternalContent);  

return new ModelAndView ("externalParserContent", modelMap);
```

Comment: could you show how you actually update `href` attribute for a link?

Comment: I have tried using the select and prepend... but that doesn't work to update the link, it only updates the text... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i did it when i needed to re-write an original string with "encoded" url:

```
    Document doc = getHtmlDocumentFromString(htmlOnly);
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    /**
     * since we would want to track link index per click - iterate links in the old fashion way (Elements is a List<Element>)
     */
    for(int linkIndexTopToBottom = 0; linkIndexTopToBottom < links.size(); linkIndexTopToBottom++){
        try{
            Element link = links.get(linkIndexTopToBottom);
            if (!UriUtils.isValidUrl(link.attr("href")))
                continue;
...
            link.attr("href",<NEW URL>);
        }catch (MalformedURLException exception){
            log.debug("Provided URL was not valid: " + links.get(linkIndexTopToBottom).attr("abs:href") + ", skipping link re-write");
        }
    }
    return doc;
```

As you can see you need to set the attribute like:

```
link.attr("href", <NEW URL>);
```

since that part was missing from your post, i were not sure whether you do it or not

**EDIT**

The appending would be exactly the same idea:
`link.attr("href", link.attr("href") + "<what you need to append with>");`

The bottom line is you need to set `href` attribute to a new value
[Example from the jSoup cook book](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes)

Comment: I like the idea of using iterate links then element for sure. Thanks for the input. however, I dont want to rewrite the url i just want to prepend the url and add sometext before the url. I will try your approach now and hope it will work. Thanks again for your reply dear.

Comment: that's true and yes it worked using your approach... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3266151 np :) don't forget to mark the question as answered so other ppl can benefit as well :)

Comment: ummm how do you do that again... just started using this site today :( Thanks.

Comment: @user3266151 :) on the answer there are up and down arrows. up arrow - vote if it was useful and since you are the one who posted the question i believe there should be an option to make question as answered